# curl lacks a pause between requests, wget lacks dynamic file output names, is there a ready alternative for sequential range of file downloads?

Tags: shell, curl, wget

Both `curl` and `wget` offer the ability to download a sequential range of files (`[1-100]` in `curl`, `{1..100}` in `wget`) but each of them have a shortcoming: `curl` offers no easy way to pause between each download in the sequence. Some servers cut off downloads after several rapid downloads, and, in any case, it is polite and proper to pause between downloads anyways to be a good scraper citizen. If one wanted to, say, pause 5 seconds between each request, my understanding is there is no way to do this without additional scripting that essentially defeats the point of having the built-in support for a sequential range by making individual requests.

A solution to this is to use `wget` which has the handy `--wait=5` flag to achieve the above desired result. Unfortunately, `wget` has other problems. It seems to struggle with special characters in URLs, and quotes around the URL can't be used because the range `{1..100}` then appears to go unrecognized. This means some manual escaping of special characters is sometimes needed. This is manageable, but annoying.

However, more importantly, `wget` has no support for naming the output dynamically (the `-O` flag is of no help here). Though `curl` offers the convenient `-o "#1.jpg"` there appears to be no way to achieve the same dynamic result in `wget` without, again, bypassing built-in sequential range support and making a scripted collection of single requests, or else having to `rename` or otherwise edit the file names after download.

This strikes me as a fairly common task: downloading a sequential range of source files, politely pausing between each request, and renaming the output dynamically. Am I missing some alternative to `curl` and `wget` that overcomes the two problems above: 1) pause between each request 2) output file names dynamically.

Comment: `aria2` might be your friend :-)

Comment: This looks very interesting! Does it support ranges of sequential urls (like [1-10] in a url)? I couldn't tell from the documentation. I also didn't see a flag like -w in wget to pause between requests but I saw an open feature request for it on github. Any thoughts @pLumo?

Comment: No sorry, cannot tell, otherwise I would posted it as an answer ;-) I just know that aria is a great tool that can do lots of good stuff.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It seems to struggle with special characters in URLs, and quotes around the URL can't be used because the range {1..100} then appears to go unrecognized.

This is because this range syntax is not actually a feature of `wget`, it's a feature of your shell (e.g. bash), which expands the arguments *before* passing them to `wget`, compare:

```
$ echo abc{1..5}
abc1 abc2 abc3 abc4 abc5
```

or

```
$ ruby -e 'p ARGV' abc{1..5}
["abc1", "abc2", "abc3", "abc4", "abc5"]
```

If you quote the argument then the shell will not expand it:

```
$ echo 'abc{1..5}'
abc{1..5}
```

However you can quote everything except the range:

```
$ echo 'abc'{1..5}'def'
abc1def abc2def abc3def abc4def abc5def
```

> However, more importantly, wget has no support for naming the output dynamically

`wget` has no features for dealing with ranges like this, because ranges like this are not a `wget` feature.

So no, it seems you can't do all of this with a single command. But you can still fit it in a oneliner:

```
for i in {1..100}; do curl "https://example.com/${i}.jpg" -o "output_${i}.jpg"; sleep 5; done
```

UNIX tools are designed to be fairly focused but easily scriptable. Some of them have grown many options to accomplish common tasks in one go, but they'll never be able to cover every use case on their own.

Answer (score 4):

Not a direct answer to "can I pause in between requests", but more so for being a "good scraper citizen".

I've succeeded with using the `--limit-rate` option after I was getting "Too many requests" from the endpoint. Had to use trial and error and 50K worked for my task.

```
curl --limit-rate 50k "https://someURL.com/resource?p=[1-100]" -o "path\to\file_#1.txt"
```

https://catonmat.net/cookbooks/curl/make-curl-slow

Answer (score 1):

With curl 7.84.0 and later, you can use the `--rate` argument described in [this blog post](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2022/05/23/curl-offers-repeated-transfers-at-slower-pace/):

> Set the fastest allowed rate with `--rate "N/U"` where N is an integer number and U is a time unit. Supported units are ‘s’ (for second), ‘m’ (for minute), ‘h’ (for hour) and ‘d’ (for day, as in a 24 hour unit). U is the time unit. The default time unit, if no “/U” is provided, is number of transfers per hour.
>
> For example, to make curl not do its requests faster than twice per minute, use `--rate 2/m` but if you rather want 25 per hour, then use `--rate 25/h`.

So to send requests no more often than once every 5 seconds (which is admittedly not the same as pausing 5 seconds between requests), you would use `--rate 12/m`.